# Tabulator List: Change the list options based on pervious list selected

Tags: javascript, tabulator

My intent is to first select a option from a list, this then changes the available values in second list.

I can't get the second list to update its values.

First the tabulator table list calls a function that returns all the countries.

- **Tabulator:**

```
{ title: "Country", field: "Country", width: 130, editor: "list", cellEdited: async function(cell){ 
                    thisCell = cell.getData(),
                    col.getDefinition().editorParams.values = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
                    table.redraw()
                    }, editorParams: { 
                        autocomplete: "true",
                        allowEmpty: true,
                        listOnEmpty: true,
                        values: getCountryData()
                    },
                    
}
```

- **JS:**

```
 var regionData;
 async function getCountryData(){
                const url = 'getCountry';
                const fetchOptions = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                };
                const res = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
                const ret = await res.json();
                await getRegionData();
                return ret;
        };
```

This works!
But after the Country is selected I would like the available list options for the region to reflect the country selected.

I have tried this:

- **JS:**

```
async function getRegionData()
        {
            const url = 'getStates';
            const fetchOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(thisCell)
                };
            const res = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
            const ret = await res.json();
            regionData = ret;
        }
```

- **Tabulator:**

```
{ title: "Province", field: "Province", width: 130, editor: "list",  editorParams: {
                    autocomplete: "true",
                    allowEmpty: true,
                    listOnEmpty: true,
                    values: regionData
                } },
```

However this does not update the values based on the regional data.

Comment: Are you sure about the variable `thisCell` in your `getRegionData`; does it properly return the region values? Could please share a codesandbox to see the code in entirety? Thanks @HappyBob